# HTTP CGI request fails to authenticate with .xml in URL

Tags: python, http, server, request

I want to send an HTTP request that looks like this (works perfectly in browser):

`http://10.1.0.100/rcp.xml?command=0x09A5&type=P_OCTET&direction=WRITE&payload=0x810006011303802c`

However, when I try to connect to to the server `http://10.1.0.100/rcp.xml?` with HTTPBasicAuth, it gives 401 response error (while in the browser it works fine). When I connect to `http://10.1.0.100` it authenticates and connects successful. I think the problem is with the `rcp.xml?`. How can I take care of this? Or do I need to do it with CGI (common gateway interface)?

Above was just to check the connection, I tested this with the code below:

```
# doesn't work
auth = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pw')
r = requests.get('http://10.1.0.100/rcp.xml?', auth=auth)
    
# does work
auth = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pw')
r = requests.get('http://10.1.0.100', auth=auth)
```

Eventually I want to send a HTTP request with parameters like this:

```
PARAMS = {'command' : '0x09A5',
            'direction' : 'WRITE',
            'type' : 'P_OCTET',
            'payload' : '0x810006011303802c',}

auth = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pw')
r = requests.get('http://10.1.0.100/rcp.xml?', auth=auth, params=PARAMS)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can remove the questionmark at the end of your url. I believe that requests will add it for you.

Comment: That does not work, still doesn't authenticate, 401 response again.